# crash ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1)

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

When I include this line I get error(crash)
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);

logcat

```
07-02 00:41:56.478 24745-24745/com.example.root.securityalert E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.root.securityalert, PID: 24745
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.root.securityalert/com.example.root.securityalert.DeviceScanActivity}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2678)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2743)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1490)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6165)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
     Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
        at com.example.root.securityalert.DeviceScanActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(DeviceScanActivity.java:213)
        at android.app.Activity.requestPermissions(Activity.java:4120)
        at com.example.root.securityalert.DeviceScanActivity.onCreate(DeviceScanActivity.java:142)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6687)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1140)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2631)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2743) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1490) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6165) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
```

code. It is making blue tooth adapter and manager.Then request permission. Then starts scan on onRequestPermissionsResult. Ihave attached requestPermissions for both ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);


            mHandler = new Handler();

            //mSend=new BluetoothSendRecv(cntxt);
            mActvty= this.getParent();
            visible = this.getIntent();

            // Use this check to determine whether BLE is supported on the device.  Then you can
            // selectively disable BLE-related features.
            if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.ble_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
            mBluetoothManager =(BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
            mBluetoothAdapter = mBluetoothManager.getAdapter();
            // Checks if Bluetooth is supported on the device.
            if (mBluetoothAdapter == null ) {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.error_bluetooth_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
                return;
            }     // Initializes a Bluetooth adapter.  For API level 18 and above, get a reference to
            // BluetoothAdapter through BluetoothManager.

            if( !mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
            {
                Intent enableBluetooth = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBluetooth, 1);
            }
            if( !mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
                Intent discoverableIntent =
                        new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
                discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
                startActivity(discoverableIntent);
            }
            // Construct the data source

            ArrayList<ViewHolder> arrayOfUsers = new ArrayList<ViewHolder>();

           // Create the adapter to convert the array to views

             adapter = new UsersAdapter(this, arrayOfUsers);
             cntxt=this.getApplicationContext();
            ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_list);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                        long id) {
                    ViewHolder entry= (ViewHolder) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                    mAddress = entry.deviceAddress;
                    Toast.makeText(cntxt, mAddress, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent i = new Intent(cntxt, BluetoothLeService.class);
                    cntxt.startService(i);
                    bindService(i, mConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);; //if checked, start service
                    //final BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
                    //mBluetoothService.mBluetoothDeviceAddress=address;
                    //mBluetoothService.mBluetoothManager=mBluetoothManager;
                    //mBluetoothService.mBluetoothAdapter = mBluetoothAdapter;
                    //mBluetoothService.mBluetoothGatt.connect();
                    /*mBluetoothService.mBluetoothGatt = */
                    //mSend.mBluetoothGatt=device.connectGatt(mActvty/*cntxt*/, false, mSend.mGattCallback);
                    //mSend.mBluetoothDeviceAddress=address;
                    //mSend.mBluetoothManager=mBluetoothManager;
                    //mSend.mBluetoothAdapter = mBluetoothAdapter;
                    //mSend.mBluetoothGatt.connect();
                    //mBluetoothService.mBluetoothGatt=mBluetoothGatt;
                    //Toast.makeText(this, R.string.error_bluetooth_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }});

            /*if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {*/
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 123);
            //}

            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION);
            ViewHolder newUser2 = new ViewHolder("adtv2","vvg2");
             adapter.add(newUser2);

        }
        ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
                //Toast.makeText(Client.this, "Service is disconnected", 1000).show();
                mBounded = false;
                mBluetoothService = null;
            }
            @Override
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
                //Toast.makeText(Client.this, "Service is connected", 1000).show();
                mBounded = true;
                BluetoothLeService.LocalBinder mLocalBinder = (BluetoothLeService.LocalBinder)service;
                Toast.makeText(cntxt, "Mithun", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mBluetoothService = mLocalBinder.getService();
                if (!mBluetoothService.initialize()) {
                    //Log.e(TAG, "Unable to initialize Bluetooth");
                    finish();
                }
                // Automatically connects to the device upon successful start-up
                // initialization.
                mBluetoothService.connect(mAddress);
            }
        };
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION: {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // Permission granted, yay! Start the Bluetooth device scan.
                    scanLeDevice(true);
                } else {
                    // Alert the user that this application requires the location permission to perform the scan.
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you add this line to your AndroidManifest.xml?  
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>`    
And maybe you can add more code to understand where and how you are using the request permission

Comment: Your crash is on `DeviceScanActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult`, can you include the code that you have in that method?

Answer (score 0):

You access `grantResults[0]` in `onRequestPermissionsResult` without checking that `grandResults.length != 0` It appears that in your error case `grantResults` is empty (thus the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0` error). Here's an example of how you could check for this case.

```
if (grantResults.length > 0 &&  // alternately check that length == 1
    grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    // Permission granted, yay! Start the Bluetooth device scan.
    scanLeDevice(true);
} else {
    // Alert the user that this application requires the location permission to perform the scan.
}
```